# Absurd issue displaying silverlight video player on differing domains

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, dns, idn

I'm having a problem displaying two silverlight movies from [different](http://haf.kicks-ass.org) [domains](http://framtidensh%C3%A4lsa.se).

They are both in the bindings of IIS, both are redirected to my private computer/server and both are loading a silverlight plugin into the browser.

The first domain displays the movies and the contents of the silverlight.
The second one doesn't.

The first domain doesn't contain the rewrite of urls that IDN causes. The second one does. However, this should obviously not pose a problem. Help to fix this is very appreciated.

My take at the problem is that Expression Encoder's video template has a bug in it by default or silverlight does... What do you think?

Edit: Not only does silverlight barf on IDN domains, but so does stack overflow. FINE THEN! The ASCII equivalent is xn--framtidenshlsa-gib.se.

Also, I might have found the reason for silverlight to barf:

> Remarks
>
> You can combine any of these options
>   to configure a generic URI parser by
>   passing the options as a parameter to
>   the
>   GenericUriParser..::.GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions)
>   constructor.
>
> The existing System..::.Uri class in
>   Silverlight does not currently provide
>   support for International Resource
>   Identifier (IRI) or Internationalized
>   Domain Name (IDN) parsing applied to
>   the domain name.
>
> Silverlight applications cannot derive
>   new classes from the Uri class.
>
> For more information on IRI support,
>   see the Remarks section for the
>   System..::.Uri class.

Comment: I get both movies in FF 3 on Windows XP. Am I overlooking the problem?

Comment: Yes, because as I have edited in, stackoverflow also fails to display the domain. See the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(v.3.0)

> The existing System..::.Uri class in
>   Silverlight does not currently provide
>   support for International Resource
>   Identifier (IRI) or Internationalized
>   Domain Name (IDN) parsing applied to
>   the domain name